# Method requires object and finds object from extended class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to create fragments in my Android app activity which I can swipe through. More specifically those fragments contain images and I want to swipe through those.

Now to accomplish this I make use of the FragmentPagerAdapter. The problem I have now is that one of my methods in a class which extends FragmentPagerAdaptor requires a Fragment object to be returned but according to the compiler it finds a different object.
This is strange, because the object I return is from a class which extends Fragment and therefore it should work in my opinion.

The problematic method is `getItem(int position)` in the `SlidesPageAdaptor` class and the error is

```
Incompatible types
Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found: ourpackagename.fragment_slides
```

SlidesPageAdaptor.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class SlidesPageAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

String[] devices;
String[] deviceDescription;

public SlidesPageAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    devices = resources.getStringArray(R.array.devices);
    deviceDescription =        resources.getStringArray(R.array.device_description);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(fragment_slides.DescriptionKey, deviceDescription[position]);
    bundle.putInt(fragment_slides.ImageIDKey, getImageID(position));

    fragment_slides fragmentSlide = new fragment_slides();
    fragmentSlide.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragmentSlide;
}

private int getImageID(int position) {

    int id = 0;
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            id = R.drawable.abc_btn_check_material;
            break;
        case 1:
            id = R.drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha;
            break;
        case 2:
            id = R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material;
            break;
    }

    return id;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return devices[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return devices.length;
}
```

}

And the `fragment_slides.class` (I know the name is bad, but not important now):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class fragment_slides extends Fragment {

public static final String ImageIDKey = "imagekey";
public static final String DescriptionKey = "descriptionkey";

    public fragment_slides() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slides_images, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if(bundle != null)
    {
        int imageID = bundle.getInt(ImageIDKey);
        String description = bundle.getString(DescriptionKey);

        setValues(view, imageID, description);
    }

    return view;

    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slides_images, container, false);
}

private void setValues(View view, int imageID, String description) {
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSlide);
    imageview.setImageResource(imageID);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSlideTest);
    textView.setText(description);
}
```

}

I don't think other activities/classes are required but I can provide them if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `fragment_slides.class` you should import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: This is the only issue which is causing the problem.. Why have you included _also_???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
fragment_slides fragmentSlide = new fragment_slides();
fragmentSlide.setArguments(bundle);
```

Since you're declaring a fragment_slides object rather than a Fragment object, the compiler thinks it isn't a Fragment. Try this instead:

```
Fragment fragmentSlide = new fragment_slides();
fragmentSlide.setArguments(bundle);
```